# Use a init in a subclass

Tags: swift, subclass, init

I have a superclass, ViewController

```
class ViewController : UIViewController { /* no init here */ }
```

And I have a lot of viewControllers who inherit form ViewController 
For example this one

```
class AddHoraire : ViewController { /* I want an init for this class */ }
```

I can I init a subclass ?  It ask me too required init I clicked on fix but does I need to write in what is it?

Here is the error :
http://www.noelshack.com/2018-52-7-1546133576-93491c85-f2eb-4b8a-bfff-35ae5763c59a.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

You typically do not define new initializers for subclasses of `UIViewController`. Doing so would require you override `init(coder:)` and `init(nibName:, bundle:)` with those exact signatures and hence no way to provide values to your custom properties.

Add a setup function to your custom VC and mention in the documentation that it must be called before the VC is ready for use:

```
class AddHoraire : ViewController {
    var anInt: Int!
    var aString: String!

    /// This method must be called before this class is ready for use
    func setup(anInt: Int, aString: String) {
        loadViewIfNeeded() // in case you need to access the outlets
        self.anInt = anInt
        self.aString = aString
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let vc = AddHoraire()
vc.setup(anInt: 42, aString: "Hello world")
```

Comment: it work great man thanks ! 
setup is executed after viewDidload but it's ok !

Comment: how can I execute that func before view did load ?

Comment: Move loadViewIfNeeded to the bottom of the func

Answer (score 0):

On your initializer attempt,

```
init(SelectedDay: String) {
    super.init()
    selectedDay = SelectedDay
}
```

you are getting the error, "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass ViewController"

Since you didn't define a designated initializer on `ViewController`, you're inheriting the designated initializer of its superclass `UIViewController`, which is `init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)`.

To fix this, add an initializer to `ViewController`. Have it call the designated initializer. You'll also have to apply the fix-it to generate `init?(coder:)`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then back in `AddHoraire`, I assume you have a `selectedDay` property. This must be set *before* calling `super.init()`. I'd also recommend not capitalizing the parameter name. Just use the same name, and distinguish between the parameter and the property by using `self.` to identify the property.

```
class AddHoraire : ViewController {
    private let selectedDay: String

    init(selectedDay: String) {
        self.selectedDay = selectedDay
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did like you said but I have that error in ViewController : 
Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented


this code is in red :

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

Comment: You need to add `init?(coder:)` to `ViewController`, did you do that? As shown above.

Comment: i paste what you write upper in my ViewController. I forgot something ?

Comment: Try deleting it. Then in the Xcode menu, select Editor -> Fix All Issues to let Xcode generate it for you.

Comment: i deleted the two init and I have " Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'ViewController' " in my AddHoraire class and I tried to only delete only required init and fix to generate but same problem of fatal error

Comment: I just add exactly what you said

Comment: If you have permission to edit your question, please add your current code. If you don't have permission, please post elsewhere and share the link so I can see what you have. This back-and-forth in the comments won't be helpful to future readers of this question.